# Is this just impatience or reputation hoarding?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, reputation

There has been a lot of discussion of the question below:

[Can I land in a different time zone before my take off time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14480/can-i-land-before-taking-off)

The question as worded is really unclear and yet has received quite a few answers.  Some of the better ones stating assumptions before giving an answer.

The question is generally silly and easy to check and answer but the bigger problem with it as I see it we allow question to stand without clarification, which for the quality of information on the site should have been made.  So this naturally begs the question in the title.

Answer (score 4):

I think the only reasonable assumption is that the OP meant with timezone tricks. There is no such thing as time travel, so "assuming you aren't asking about time travel" is almost something that should go without saying. I can't support a position that nobody should have answered until the OP clarified about time travel vs time zones.

That said, it's not a great question and even when you reword to indicate that both cross-IDL and very-local less-than-an-hour flights across an ordinary time zone are ok, all you now have is a list question. That's the issue with it, not the "mystery" of whether the OP means time travel or not.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I missed this one - last two days have been chaos for me packing up to leave Vancouver. As with the other close voters, I've closed it as not constructive.

If however, they'd asked about flights like Conchorde where you arrive before you leave (without crossing a timezone) then it might be more relevant and interesting.

I thin they could edit it and probably reopen, but now we have a bunch of assumption answers, as you mentioned; so it'd be better as a new question.